# How to make provider listener listen only once

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, provider, flutter-provider

I am geting input(text) using textfield and displaying in a list, I am using onchanged property of textfield and provider to update the text of new element in list but, all elements in the list update to onChanged's new value, once the element is added to list I want it to stop listening to changes of onChanged. So, that I can display list with different elements. How do I achieve that.

```
TextField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: kTextFieldDecocation.copyWith(
                        hintText: 'B Name'),
                    onChanged: (newbName) {
                      Provider.of<BNameControllerClass>(context,
                              listen: false)
                          .newBorrowerName(newbName);
                    },
                  ),
```

List element's text

```
Text(
                          Provider.of<BNameControllerClass>(context,
                                  listen: true)
                              .bName,

                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        );
```

provider class

```
class BNameControllerClass extends ChangeNotifier {
  String bName = 'Ganesh';
  newBorrowerName(String newName) {
    bName = newName;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `List<String> textsFromInput = [];`
Generate text widgets with `ListView.generate().`
Then in TextField you can use `onSubmitted: (value) => textsFromInput.add(value)`
Depending on what state management you have you can then call setState() or handle list rebuilding with bloc builder `buildWhen: previous.textsFromInput.length != current.textsFromInput.length` or with provider.